# Typescript Express server giving "Cannot use import statement outside of module"

Tags: node.js, typescript, module, async-await, commonjs

Typescript 3.8 introduced top level await functionality. This is great for me! I enable it by setting the `module` and `moduleResolution` settings in `tsconfig` to `ESNext` and `node` respectively.

Suddenly a problem though, my application no longer boots. Instead throwing an error:

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`
```

Looking over my code I know exactly where its throwing the error, but not sure how to fix it. I've added `type:module` to my `package.json`, but still not getting anything to work.

Here is a look at how my `boot.ts` entry file looks. Under the hood we're starting an express server.

```
import { Server } from "./api/server";
import {Storage} from "./boot_storage";
import BackedLogger from "./logger/logger";


const storage = new Storage();

storage.boot()
    .then(() => {
        Server.Instance.startServer(BackedLogger)
    });
```

I know this isn't a ton to go on. I still don't understand imports in Typescript/Node well. I'm more than willing to answer questions and give clarification.

**I'm more than willing to change how my application starts in order to get this to work, that's how nice the top level async/await is going to be for me.**